# Android web development problem

Tags: android, html, canvas, css

I want to make gradient text only with css3 or html5 working on Android. I tried with css3 but on android there's a little problem. I tried this http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/07/24/pure-css-text-gradient-no-pngs/. Here's how it looks like in android http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/5014/androidw.png . Can somebody tell me how to fix it, or another way to do it, no matter with css3 or html5 canvas?

```
header h1 {
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
margin-top: 0px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
margin: 23px 0 0 77px;
```

}

```
header h1 a {
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

}

```
header h1:after {
content: 'Company name';
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
text-shadow: -1px 1px 2px #232323;
color: #dadada;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a browser issue.

Here is a link to a cross-browser css gradient generator.

Try creating any gradient and try it. If it works, then it's a browser issue.

Here is the link: [CSS Gradient Generator](http://projects.korrelboom.com/gradient-generator/#top%7CMagenta%7CSlateGray)

Let me know if it sorts the problem for you.

Comment: I can't understand how this can work for text, because this is for background gradients, and I need text gradient. Please answer me how if I'm wrong.